# Laravel cannot connect to Azure MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, azure, laravel-5, azure-sql-database

I am working on a Laravel product which has to connect to Azure MySql server. I have the following config in `.env` file:

> /.ENV

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=hostname.mysql.database.azure.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=username@hostname
DB_PASSWORD=1234567890
```

But Laravel cannot connect to the MySQL properly, and give this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'123.123.123.123' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

It seems like Laravel has replaced the `hostname` with server ip in the `username`. How can I make Laravel not replacing the `hostname`, and `connect` to the Azure MySQL properly.

Comment: I'm not 100% to be honest. But you could try a) wrapping the value in quotes b) adding http(s): `"https://hostname..."`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Do you open client ip on firewall rules?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT I don't have access to the server/firewall settings. Can you tell me more about the firewall rules which would related to my problem. Then I can if the server support department could help me.

Comment: @ChitoCheng You could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal#configure-a-server-level-firewall-rule) it seems your issue is a firewall issue.

Comment: doesn't look like firewall issue. The error is clearly given by mysql. Can you check Mysql user settings if permission is available for username@host

Comment: @ChitoCheng Do you try add your IP on the firewall?

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. Could you fix it? It's not a firewall issue, since I can connect from the same host using golang, or by using the connection code given by azure. It's something with laravel messing with the aweful username format "user@mysql-name". Note that the "@" here doesn't mean "use this host", it's just part of the username.

Answer (score 2):

Azure requires SSL connections by default. You can turn these off in Azure or use:

```php
'options'   => array(
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/certs/client-key.pem',
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/certs/client-cert.pem',
                \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/certs/ca.pem',
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to do with the user permissions on the MySQL server itself. You can try to create a new MySQL User using `username`@`%` (which is username with any hostname`.

E.g.

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then update your Laravel `.env` file with the new username and password.